# Edit custom post type page with ACF repeater fields throws ‘Service Unavailable’ error

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using latest version of WP and toolset types plugin to create custom post type. When I go on the custom post type edit page( Dashboard > Post Type > Edit ) in admin part, its throwing

> Service Unavailable..The service is temporarily unavailable. Please
>   try again later

The custom post type( Article ) is having one ACF repeater field. So when article is having number of subfields on that repeater, in that case the edit article page is throwing 500 internal server error.

I followed the steps for debugging the site by deactivating all Plugins and then trie to activate plugins one by one. And found that there are two plugins ‘WP Review’ & ‘WP User Avatar’. On deactivating these plugins the edit article( with repeater subfields ) is loading though its very slow. But when I am activating any one of these two plugin, then again 500 internal server is throwing for the articles having repeater subfields.

Please suggest if anyone faced this type of issue.

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: did you try turning on wp-debug in wp-config and acutally see what the error is, or check your error log?  That will help me help you.  and post your code here for review.

Comment: Yes I had turned on the debug as true and didnot find any error related to this issue.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Which code I will provide, This is coming for edit page for one custom post type created by Types plugin.